# ¿Como añadir una Cabecera en Excel con VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

Estoy aprendiendo VB.NET e intentado hacer un pequeño programa para rellanar algunas celdas in excel, esto no ha sido muy difícil ya que hay mucha documentación, pero ahora trato de insertar una imagen en la cabecera de la hoja Excel y no logro saber como hacerlo. He leído todos los documentos de Microsoft, pero no logro insertar la imagen en la cabecera.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda.

---

He visto varias propiedades e interfaces pero no he tenido exito:

- HeaderFooter.Picture Property
- PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture Property
- HeaderFooter Interface

[Microsoft Office Interop Excel](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia)

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim ExcelProces() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim wb = New Application
        Dim sheet = wb.Workbooks.Add

        'Cabecera de Excel
        PageSetup.Rigth.AddImage("F:\Programacion\.NET\Prueba_Excel\opensource_Pequeño.png") 'Prueba para añadir cabecera recomendado (no ha funcionado), he probado a hacerlo con sheet.PageSetup.Right.AddImage() y tampoco.

        'inserta Hello World en la casilla correspondiente
        sheet.ActiveSheet.cells(8, 5) = "Hola Mundo"


        'Save and Launch
        sheet.SaveAs("F:\Programacion\.NET\Prueba_Excel\PruebaHeader.xlsx")
        wb.Quit()

        sheet = Nothing
        wb = Nothing
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Close()

        'Fuerza el cierre de Excel
        For Each mykill As Process In ExcelProces
            mykill.Kill()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

## Solución

Gracias por la ayuda prestada, a continuación dejo el enlace al SO en ingles donde también formule la pregunta y me han ayudado a solucionarlo.

[Insertar HeaderFooter con texto o imagenes (Inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536173/9535487)

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Creo que deberías probar con algo tipo `PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture.Filename="D:\imagen\mi_imagen.jpg"`

Comment: Buenos días, Muchas gracias por la bienvenida. He intentado lo que dices pero sin exito, o me da error o si se ejecuta el programa no inserta la cabecera.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu código?

Comment: Buenos días, He subido el código. Como puedes ver es muy simple y sin el "PageSetup" funciona correctamente.